# Is it possible to addExtra() to Intent with Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible to add extras to an intent which has ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT as action?

Here is how I create my Intent:

```
// Request code for creating a PDF document.
const val CREATE_FILE = 1

private fun createFile(pickerInitialUri: Uri) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        type = "application/pdf"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "invoice.pdf")
        // Set extra here
        putExtra("url", url)

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker before your app creates the document.
        putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, pickerInitialUri)
    }
    startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE)
}
```

And I obtain the extras in the `onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)` method.

I obtain my extras like this:

```
val extra = data?.getStringExtra("url")
```

But extras are always `null`

Comment: `putExtra("url", url)` You can add it. It does not harm. But you dont get it back. Unfortunately. I also would like to get such extras back. You are not alone!

Comment: [ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT) does not specify that it handles an "url" extra so sadly it's lost because activities are under no obligation to rebounce unknown extras into result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I obtain the extras in the onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) method.

That works for approximately zero `Intent` actions and apps responding to them. It will not work for `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.